# How to suppress `When done with a buffer, type C-x #` warning message?

Tags: emacsclient, echo-area, message

When I open a buffer I keep seeing following message in the minibuffer:
`When done with a buffer, type C-x #` . Is it possible completely to suppress this message?

---

I'm using `emacsclient -t -q` to open `GNU Emacs 26.3`. Following lines are in the `.zshrc` file.

```bash
export ALTERNATE_EDITOR=""
export EDITOR="emacsclient -t"
```

Comment: I think you need to add a bit more context... I guess that you open a buffer using `emacsclient`, right? In that case you can add the option `--no-wait`. The default for `emacsclient` is to wait for you to edit the buffer and mark it as done using `C-x #`, hence the message in the minibuffer.

Comment: Yes sir, I am using `emacsclient -t -q <file.py>` to open files. Usually I close it using `C-x C-c` to get back to shell and re-open the same file. I have added `--no-wait` parameter but it directly shuts down the `emacs` before opening it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to avoid that message with Emacs earlier than 28.1 is to invoke `emacsclient` with the `-n` (`--nowait`) option.

---

Starting with Emacs 28.1 (basically, current upstream at the time of writing), [there is a variable to do that](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=ff5a3c74fc45c80f2c8c272f259dbba84b7c3f66):

Customizing `server-client-instructions` and toggling it off *should* turn off that message, <s>but I cannot confirm: either my emacs session is curdled or there is something else that's funky</s>.

The doc string of the variable says:

> Documentation:
>
> If non-nil, display instructions on how to exit the client on connection.
>
> If nil, no instructions are displayed.

EDIT: after restarting emacs (actually, a newer version that I had installed - this was an opportunity to kill the old emacs and start with the new version), I can see the variable and it does seem to work as described. The explanation here is that I went from a version that did not have the variable to a version that did.

Here's the [commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=ff5a3c74fc45c80f2c8c272f259dbba84b7c3f66) that added the variable.

EDIT (in response to the OP's comment): to customize the variable, ask for its description with `C-h v server-client-instructions RET`, hit the `customize` link where it says "You can `customize` this variable" and when the customize interface comes up, hit the `Toggle` button to toggle it off (nil) and then hit `Apply and Save` to save it permanently.

Comment: What customization should I apply? I tried adding `--no-wait` but it didn't help

Comment: I was assuming you knew how to use the Customize interface. See edited answer.

Comment: Hm seems like I don't have any `server-client-instructions` variable :-( but I have a variable called `server-clients` which does not have any customize option

Comment: It may be that the variable is recent: I didn't check history in git. I'll do that and report back.

Comment: It is very recent: it was inroduced in Emacs 28.1 about two months ago. The only way to avoid the message with earlier emacs is `emacsclient -n`.

Comment: `emacsclient -n` kills itself without opening `emacs` :-( Let me try it with `Emacs 28.1 ` if everything works fine I will keep using it

Comment: Where can I install  Emacs 28.1` ? From ubuntu when I do `sudo snap install emacs --classic` it keeps installing `emacs 27.1`

Comment: AFAIK, it has not been released yet. I keep a clone of the git repo and build from source (which is probably beyond what most people are willing to do).

Comment: This didn't work with emacs28 on my end where it crashes right away :(